# What is Open Build Studio and how does it work?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, opensuse, packaging

I'm just curious to know what is Open Build Studio. The website says it's got 43,959 projects, with 363,784 packages, in 67,556 repositories. Judging by those numbers, does it mean that OpenSUSE has the largest repositories among the Linux distros? Also, I'd like know how can I utilise this resource with YAST or by any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not "Open Build Studio", it's "[Open Build Service](http://openbuildservice.org/)".

OBS is a system to go from source-and-packaging-metadata for any distribution to repositories with prebuilt packages for (various versions of) those distributions. It allows packagers to upload the source, and be certain that the uploaded source gets compiled in a clean and somewhat reproducible environment so that their users can install what they meant them to install.

It does this by automating most of the process -- generating the build chroot, doing the actual compilation, signing the resulting packages (if applicable), copying them to the right repositories, signing the repositories (if applicable), and repository management.

Since OBS is capable of building packages for not just openSUSE, but also for Fedora-like and Debian-like distributions, you may find that some of those packages aren't in fact available for openSUSE, but only for those other distributions. Also, those numbers count a package once per version and probably once per architecture too, rather than one time for all versions together, which skews the numbers a bit more.

In that light, the question of whether that means openSUSE does indeed have more packages than other distributions is difficult to answer. E.g., my aptitude tells me that Debian Jessie has about 67000 packages available; but that counts packages only once for all versions, rather than once per version per package...